# Show WindowsForm in the center of the Screen (Dual Screen)

Tags: .net, winforms, multiple-monitors

I have Dual Monitors and want displaying a windows form in the center of the screen. (I have a variable MonitorId=0 or 1).

I have:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen[] allScreens=System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens;
System.Windows.Forms.Screen myScreen = allScreens[0];

int screenId = RegistryManager.ScreenId;
// DualScreen management
if (screenId > 0)
{
    // has 2nd screen
    if (allScreens.Length == 2)
    {
        if (screenId == 1)
            myScreen = allScreens[0];
        else
            myScreen = allScreens[1];
    }
}

this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(myScreen.Bounds.Left, 0);
this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
```

But this code does not seem to work each time... It displays the form every time on the main screen only.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
foreach(var screen in Screen.AllScreens)
{
   if (screen.WorkingArea.Contains(this.Location))
   {
      var middle = (screen.WorkingArea.Bottom + screen.WorkingArea.Top) / 2;
      Location = new System.Drawing.Point(Location.X, middle - Height / 2);
      break;
   }
}
```

Note that this will not work if the top-left corner is not on any of the screens, so it may be better to find the screen with the least distance from the center of the form instead.

**Edit**

If you want to display on a *given* screen, you must set `this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;`

Try using this code:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen[] allScreens = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens;
System.Windows.Forms.Screen myScreen = allScreens[0];

int screenId = RegistryManager.ScreenId;
if (screenId > 0)
{
    myScreen = allScreens[screenId - 1];
}

Point centerOfScreen = new Point((myScreen.WorkingArea.Left + myScreen.WorkingArea.Right) / 2,
                                 (myScreen.WorkingArea.Top + myScreen.WorkingArea.Bottom) / 2);
this.Location = new Point(centerOfScreen.X - this.Width / 2, centerOfScreen.Y - this.Height / 2);

this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
```

Comment: I dont need to display the form on the same screen that is actually located (`if (screen.WorkingArea.Contains(this.Location))`) but in dependence of the `screeenID`