# what's the difference between the sum of a screens WorkingArea and it's Bounds

Tags: c#, .net, screen, multiple-monitors

In the .NET, what is the difference between

```
myScreen.WorkingArea.Left + myScreen.WorkingArea.Right
```

and

```
myscreen.Bounds
```

Comment: Left + Right is an arbitrary number.  Use Right - Left or Width.  The difference with Bounds.Width is the 'appbars'.  Like the Windows Taskbar, there can be more than one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Working Area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea.aspx):

> Gets the working area of the display.
>   The working area is the desktop area
>   of the display, excluding taskbars,
>   docked windows, and docked tool bars.

[Bounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.bounds.aspx):

> Gets the bounds of the display.

So, in the first instance you're working with *actual* space, while in the second *visual* space.

Answer (score 4):

`WorkingArea` excludes Taskbar (and a few other thinds. see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea%28VS.90%29.aspx)). `Bounds` includes everything.

`WorkingArea` is an instance of Rectangle.
Rectangle.Left gives the x coordinate. 
Rectangle.Right gives x coordinate + width.

Adding Left and Right doesn't make too much sense to me.

Comment: Perhaps an example helps.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865879/show-windowsform-in-the-center-of-the-screen-dual-screen