# Is it possible to set the Maximum Width for a Form but leave the Maximum Height Unrestricted?

Tags: c#, winforms

For some reason if you set both of the width and the height of Form.MaximumSize to zero it will let you have an unrestricted window size, however if you want to set a limit you have to do it for both width and height at the same time.  I want a fixed width but no limit on height.

```
    // No Limits
    this.MaximumSize = new Size(0,0);

    // Form Height will be stuck at 0
    int ArbitraryWidth = 200;
    this.MaximumSize = new Size(ArbitraryWidth, 0);
```

Comment: Have you considered intercepting the resize events and manually forcing the form's size not to exceed your arbitrary width?

Comment: @ose - Yes but it seems a little ugly

Comment: unfortunate architectural decision => slightly ugly code :(

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use INT_MAX since that's the theoretical limit that can be represented by a `Size` anyway:

```
//Max width 200, unlimited height
this.MaximumSize = new Size(200, int.MaxValue);
```

Answer (score 4):

I know the question is a couple of years old but I met the same problem and what I did was to set one of the parameter to the resolution of the screen, assuming the size of the form cannot exceed the size of the screen.

```
this.MaximumSize = new Size(200, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
```

Hopes this helps someone.

Comment: Works for me although in practice it's probably not different from INT_MAX.  Thanks!

Comment: This will cause problems when your resolution changes. E.g. If you plug your laptop into a projector for a demo. It also fails if your secondary, tertiary, etc. display is taller than your primary display and you move the form to that display, or if you have stacked monitors and want to stretch it across multiple screens.

Comment: Also, even in the context of a single display, it usually makes more sense to use `Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height` than `Bounds` for the reasons described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797699/whats-the-difference-between-the-sum-of-a-screens-workingarea-and-its-bounds

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to set the Maximum Width for a Form but leave the
>   Maximum Height Unrestricted?

Not really. You could simulate it as follows:

```
    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetMaximumWidth();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetMaximumWidth();
    }

    private void SetMaximumWidth()
    {
        if (Width > 200)
            Width = 200;
    }
```