# How to set a maximize limit for windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a project which has several forms which are connected to a SQL database (read and write). Apart from the parent form, each form starts in center position and in the size I set for it in the properties (which apparently it is considered by the system as the minimum size). When I click the maximize button it goes full screen and that is my problem.

I want the child form to be just a little smaller than the main form (so that I can see the header from behind). When I write my preferred maximum size in properties field it just doesn't work.

I used the first solution written here: [Is it possible to set the Maximum Width for a Form but leave the Maximum Height Unrestricted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527142/is-it-possible-to-set-the-maximum-width-for-a-form-but-leave-the-maximum-height). It gave me a restriction for the maximized size. However, it not only makes the form get out of center, but as soon as I click on the form it goes back to minimum size.

The other issue is that my project is suppose to run on more than one computer with different resolutions. So, i don't think giving it a specific size would help.

Bottom line is, I want the size of my child form to maximize to a limit just a little smaller than the parent form which is full screen.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: sorry. This was the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527142/is-it-possible-to-set-the-maximum-width-for-a-form-but-leave-the-maximum-height

Comment: are these forms mdi child forms ? From what I read I think not. Is there a reason for not making this project MDI ?

Comment: This is not how windows work, maximize is a system command, which makes the window go full screen. You can either disable default maximize command and handle them yourself or make the form a MDI container as per @GuidoG suggestion.

Comment: Hi, why don´t you just catch the event and set the size of your window to what ever you want? Take a look over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295999/event-when-a-window-gets-maximized-un-maximized

Comment: @GuidoG: it is MDI. But as I said I am quit new to this and I get stuck quit often in things that may seem really easy for others :-(

Comment: if it is MDI than it all should work as you want it. Have you changed any form properties ? Do you assign the MDIParent property of the child forms ?

Comment: I think that is exactly what I need. How do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're trying to create a Multiple Document Interface (MDI) style application.  This style isn't very common any more, but here are some [examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e(v=vs.110).aspx) on how to do so.

The StackOverflow example you gave uses the MaximumSize property.  That property doesn't apply when the user clicks the 'maximize' button at the top right.  It is used for when the form is configured to allow resizing (by grabbing the handle at bottom right).  *Maximize* functionality will either fill the full screen, or for MDI applications, the entire MDI parent window -- and it's always been that way.

Comment: we are still building many new winforms projects and this is because just about every client wants an MDI application. So I am not sure if this style isn't common any more. Its not when building apps that I agree but for winforms I think it is still common

Comment: Meh!  I did WinForms (VB3-6) for 10 years before it was even called that.  I rarely see any requirements for it now - and Microsoft dropped MDI in WPF.

Comment: Yes in WPF it is gone that is what I said it is only a requirement when buidling winforms applications, not apps.  And by the why I believe that devexpress brought MDI back in WPF.

Comment: Actually, if it works like "when the form is configured to allow resizing (by grabbing the handle at bottom right)" that would be perfect for me. But I cannot resize it like that because it is disabled. If I could do that then I would leave the maximize command on control box alone and used this. BTW, it is an MDI